# how do repository search by value member?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

How do i set text to repositoryLookupedit by searching the value member ?
What i want is in `grade` column when i type the value member it shows the display member. `E.g` when i type `1` it set grade column into `D`

[image]

here's my code

```
   private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Grade", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(int));
        dt.Rows.Add("A", 4);
        dt.Rows.Add("B", 3);
        dt.Rows.Add("C", 2);
        dt.Rows.Add("D", 1);
        repositoryItemLookUpEdit1.DataSource = dt;
        repositoryItemLookUpEdit1.DisplayMember = dt.Columns["Grade"].ToString();
        repositoryItemLookUpEdit1.ValueMember = dt.Columns["Value"].ToString();
        repositoryItemLookUpEdit1.NullText = "";
        repositoryItemLookUpEdit1.PopupFormMinSize = new Size(100, 50);

        DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
        dt2.Columns.Add("colA", typeof(String));
        dt2.Columns.Add("colB", typeof(String));
        dt2.Columns.Add("colC", typeof(String));
        for(int i =0; i < 15; i++)
        {
            dt2.Rows.Add(i.ToString() + "a", i.ToString() + "b", i.ToString()+"c");
        }
        gridControl1.DataSource = dt2;
        gridView1.BeginUpdate();
        DataColumn col2 = dt2.Columns.Add("Grade", typeof(int));
        GridColumn column2 = gridView1.Columns.AddVisible(col2.ColumnName);
        column2.Caption = col2.Caption;
        column2.Name = col2.ColumnName;
        gridView1.EndUpdate();
        gridView1.Columns["Grade"].ColumnEdit = repositoryItemLookUpEdit1;
    }
```

what i have tried is putting a code in the gridview event. but it won't worked

```
 private void gridView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {            
        if(e.KeyValue == 49)
        {
            gridView1.SetFocusedRowCellValue("Grade", 1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Devexpress support is amazing - I'd recommend asking them directly.

Comment: nevermind, just found out a way about it

Answer (score 0):

first, set searchmode for repository into popup

```
repositoryItemLookUpEdit1.SearchMode = DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.SearchMode.OnlyInPopup;
```

and then add code to gridview and repositoryitemlookupedit keydown events

```
  private void gridView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.NumPad1 || e.KeyCode == Keys.D || e.KeyValue == 49)
        {
            gridView1.SetFocusedRowCellValue("Grade", 1);
        }
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.NumPad2 || e.KeyCode == Keys.C || e.KeyValue == 50)
        {
            gridView1.SetFocusedRowCellValue("Grade", 2);
        }
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.NumPad3 || e.KeyCode == Keys.B || e.KeyValue == 51)
        {
            gridView1.SetFocusedRowCellValue("Grade", 3);
        }
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.NumPad4 || e.KeyCode == Keys.A || e.KeyValue == 52)
        {
            gridView1.SetFocusedRowCellValue("Grade", 4);
        }
    }
    private void repositoryItemLookUpEdit1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.NumPad1 || e.KeyCode == Keys.D || e.KeyValue == 49)
        {
            gridView1.SetFocusedRowCellValue("Grade", 1);
        }
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.NumPad2 || e.KeyCode == Keys.C || e.KeyValue == 50)
        {
            gridView1.SetFocusedRowCellValue("Grade", 2);
        }
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.NumPad3 || e.KeyCode == Keys.B || e.KeyValue == 51)
        {
            gridView1.SetFocusedRowCellValue("Grade", 3);
        }
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.NumPad4 || e.KeyCode == Keys.A || e.KeyValue == 52)
        {
            gridView1.SetFocusedRowCellValue("Grade", 4);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try SearchLookUpEdit instead of simple LookUpEdit. SearchLookUpEdit provides variety of searching options.